# How do you run multiple instance of gud in emacs

Tags: emacs, gdb, gud

I want to debug C++ and and php in the same emacs instance (using gdb and a php debugging mode that uses gud-common-init). When I fire both up everything just gets messed up. My guess is that gud.el doesn't support this.

Does anybody know if a way to do this exists?

Comment: Could you describe your PHP debugging environment? I've experimented with Xdebug & GEBEN, and that's certainly decent (after a little customisation), but not spectacular; and I can't seem to inspect the variables in other stack frames which is a problem. I'm curious to know what the alternatives are.

Comment: I too am looking for a reasonable way to debug PHP, preferably within emacs GUD.  Please share how you're doing it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From **gdb** help:

```
To run GDB in text command mode, use `gud-gdb'.  You need to use
text command mode to debug multiple programs within one Emacs
session.
```

So as you say Emacs don't allow simultaneously full featured debugging, but allow simultaneously many text mode debuggers (like M-x shell).

Answer (score 0):

There is a rewrite of *gud* called [realgud](https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr/) and that support multiple debuggers. It doesn't support php, see [this](https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr/wiki/Debuggers-Supported) for a list of supported debuggers, but then I am not aware that *gud* does either. But there are [instructions for how to add a new debugger](https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr/wiki/How-to-add-a-new-debugger).